# Why would I want tourism with cultural victory disabled?

Tags: civilization-6

When playing with cultural victory disabled in Civilization VI, do I have any use at all for tourism? Does it impact the game?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no other use for [tourism](http://civ6.gamepedia.com/Tourism) other than achieving a cultural victory in Civilization VI.

Culture still has use (for policies, etc.) but the boosts it can provide to tourism are also useless with the victory condition disabled.

**Additional:**  It is worth mentioning, as noted in [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/civ/comments/56bg82/is_civ_vi_tourism_too_boring_or_why_the_cultural/), that in Civ V tourism had other uses such as your happiness and trade, especially when ideologies were being chosen. However, in Civ VI that mechanic is not present.